# Project Euler # 37 Truncatable primes

Tags: python, python-3.x

truncatable numbers are defined as follows:
The number 3797 has an interesting property. Being prime itself, it is possible to continuously remove digits from left to right, and remain prime at each stage: 3797, 797, 97, and 7. Similarly we can work from right to left: 3797, 379, 37, and 3.

Find the sum of the only eleven primes that are both truncatable from left to right and right to left.

NOTE: 2, 3, 5, and 7 are not considered to be truncatable primes.

```
def is_prime(number):
    """returns True for a prime number, False otherwise."""
    factor = 2
    while factor * factor <= number:
        if number % factor == 0:
            return False
        factor += 1
    return True


def get_truncatable(n):
    """returns truncatable numbers within range n."""
    for number in range(9, n, 2):
        if is_prime(number):
            check = 0
            for index in range(-1, -len(str(number)), -1):
                less_right = str(number)[:index]
                if not is_prime(int(less_right)):
                    check += 1
            if check == 0:
                for index in range(1, len(str(number))):
                    less_left = str(number)[index:]
                    if not is_prime(int(less_left)):
                        check += 1
                if check == 0:
                    yield number


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print((list(get_truncatable(1000000))))
```

Code should return `[23, 37, 53, 73, 313, 317, 373, 797, 3137, 3797, 739397]` or their equivalent sum: `748317`

it returns: `[11, 13, 17, 23, 31, 37, 53, 71, 73, 113, 131, 137, 173, 197, 311, 313, 317, 373, 797, 1373, 1997, 3137, 3797, 7331, 73331, 739397]`

and as you can see '31' in my code is truncatable as well as all of the other numbers, when I searched I found codes giving the first output.

How exactly the difference is coming from? am i wrong? am I right?

Comment: 1 is not a prime number, so any number beginning or ending in 1 is not left- and right- truncatable. The first truncatable prime is 23.

Answer (score 1):

Your `is_prime` returns True for 1. You can add it as a special case.

```
def is_prime(number):
    """returns True for a prime number, False otherwise."""
    factor = 2
    while factor * factor <= number:
        if number % factor == 0:
            return False
        # additional speedup here
        factor += 1 + factor % 2
    return number > 1
```

Comment: I did and it runs perfectly fine, thank you. Do you have any suggestions regarding efficiency? (takes like 10 secs to show output)

Comment: @emadboctor It is fruitless to continue checking even numbers larger than 2 as factors, so a ~50% speedup can be realized by checking only 2 and odd numbers. I revised my answer to incorporate this.

Comment: @emadboctor You may also try as a first step to find all the prime numbers under `n` and use this set in the `is_prime` check, rather than doing the calculation over and over again for each test. A common approach for discovering primes under relatively smaller upper bounds is the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way to do this would be to generate a set of primes as strings.  Then check for entries in the list that meet the truncation criteria (which is easier to express with substrings):

First generate string primes up to 1000000.  There are tons of ways to do this but the sieve of Eratosthenes is simple and fast:

```
R      = 1000000
sieve  = [True]*R
primes = set()
for n in range(2,R+1):
    if sieve[n-1]:
        primes.add(str(n))
        sieve[n*n-1::n] = [False]*len(range(n*n-1,R,n))
```

then check for eligible primes:

```
truncable = []
for p in primes:
    if len(p) == 1: continue
    if all(p[:i] in primes and p[i:] in primes for i in range(1,len(p))):
        truncable.append(int(p))

print(sum(truncable))
```